# unable to call one button from without button

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have two buttons which are encapsulated with forms at SpringMVC/Thymeleaf.The interesting thing is I am not if I remove upper button, when I click second button nothing happens. I meant I am not able to call the PostMaping inside Controller which can be called if first button there. It could be an interesting issue for you but I tested it many times and could not find a reason why that happens.Could you please look at the code and let me know how it happens?

First Button:(encapsulated with form)

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="/showlimit"   th:action="@{/showlimit}" th:object="${internetCustomer}" method="post">
<button type="submit"
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-primary">
    <th:block th:text="#{label.customerdetails.button.limits}">
       First Button
    </th:block>
</button>
```

Second Button:(Encapsulated with form to call PostMapping at Controller)

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="/showlimit/{customerId}(customerId='123')}" th:action="@{/showlimit}"  th:object="${limitModel}" method="post">
 <button type="submit"
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-  primary">
    <th:block th:text="#{label.customerdetails.button.limits}">
        Second Button
    </th:block>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you submit your second form, you are making a POST request to the url `/showlimit/123`. Since you are passing a parameter in an URL to show something, this should be a GET mapping, not a POST one. This affects how your request is processed by the controller, since POST request parameters are expected in the body, not the URL.

To pass this parameter to the controller, use the following mapping and method:

```
@GetMapping(/showlimit/{customerId})
public String foo(@PathVariable String customerId, Model model){
...
}
```

And change the method in your form to `GET`.